# MAgento 2 import customer with custom attribute?

Tags: magento2, import, customer-attribute

How to import customer Using CSV with custom attribute?

Comment: have you tried with add new column into csv file and import?

Comment: I have export sheet and them with some modification I import it and Now its working. Thanks !!

Comment: You can add answer here so other users have helpful in future.

Comment: I am having 1 multiselect box custom attribute but when I import it. I didn't get those values as selected which I added in csv for that multiselect customer attribute. How I can import it through csv?